# Vocabulary contains too many choices

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Hello I've created a vocabulary which contains a lot of ingredients can i make it easier to choose them. At the moment it is a long list. If it is somehow possible to make a search form where i can select multiple ingredients it would be great. Modules or other soloutions?

Comment: Are you selecting from a list on a node edit form? Have you tried using the autocomplete widget?

Comment: Yes at the moment i'm using checkboxes/radio - I have tried autocomplete widget but that didn't work me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module. It provides autocomplete functionality with multiselect capability. Using the multiselect field you can hold ctrl while selecting to keep the list open. [Here's a demo](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: Thank you that was what i was looking after. - How can i use it as a filter in view?

Comment: I'm not familiar with implementing the module, but the under the usage header on the module page it indicates it should work on any 20+ item select list by default. You may need to add a selector to target the views filter specifically on the Chosen module administration page.